# Конвертировать из Bigint в значение datetime

Tags: sql-server

Имеется значение 1530181751 в типе Bigint. Как я могу его преобразовать в DateTime в MsSQL. 
нашел вот [такую тему](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650320/convert-from-bigint-to-datetime-value) 
но дату преобразовывает не верно, получаю значение 1970-01-19 01:03:01.000, а должно быть предположительно 28.06.2018 15:29:12

Предположительно потому что время похоже без учета часового пояса

Comment: Откуда вы взяли это значение? Есть несколько техник хранения дат в виде целого, нужно знать, какая их них используется.

Comment: Умножайте на 1000 исходное число или ищите преобразование UNIXTIME в DateTime

Comment: из базы данных postgresql

Comment: По ссылке - это время в формате UNIX

Comment: "должно быть предположительно" - это как? Если хотите преобразовать что-то к чему-то, то результат должен быть известен точно, а не "предположительно"

Comment: *из базы данных postgresql* - в базу данных SQL server? Если нет - поправьте тег.

Comment: https://www.stev.org/post/mssqlconvertunixtimestamptodatetime

Comment: в  postgresql  я преобразовал вот так to_timestamp(1530181751) и получилась эта дата

Comment: Akina Я связываю две таблицы одна находится в MSSQL другая в postgresql, делаю это чрез связаные сервера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отметки времени в виде целого хранятся, как правило, по следующей методике: Это количество дней, секунд, миллисекунд, микросекунд или наносекунд, прошедших с некой начальной даты. Т.е. определяется двумя параметрами: точность (или же приращение за один день) и начальная дата. Обычное линейное уравнение. Можно найти коэффициенты, если точно известны две закодированные даты.

**UPD 1**

ИЗ справки по PostgreSQL:

> to_timestamp(double precision) - преобразует время в стиле Unix в стандартное врем

Unix - значит отсчет от 01.01.1970. Но double precision говорит о том, что это количество дней.

Для преобразования просто прибавьте это кол-во дней к 01.01.1970

**UPD 2**
Если дата хранится не в виде целого, а дробного, то (во всех случаях, что я встречал) приращение за один день соответствует единице. 1 часу - 1/24, 1 минуте - 1/(24*60) и т.д. пока хватает точности.

Comment: dateadd(s, convert(bigint, date_create), convert(datetime, '1-1-1970 00:00:00'))
По ссылке которую я давал убрал из кода деление на 1000 и все заработало. 
Спасибо Герман за подробное объяснение, теперь хоть понимаю по какому принципу идет преобразование

Comment: Если нужны еще и часы, минуты, секунды, то нужно взять и дробную часть.